# In Azure logic app i am getting DirectApiAuthorizationRequired

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In azure logic app, I am getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "DirectApiAuthorizationRequired",
        "message": "The request must be authenticated only by Shared Access scheme."
    }
}
```

but as for as I know SAS token for authorization will append to url so no need to pass any authorization.

But i am unable to solve the above problem.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me. When do you get this error? When calling the Logic App using a HTTP-request or on an HTTP-action in your Logic App? 
Can you provide some more information?

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure you have the url between double quotes.

```
curl "https://production.centralus.logic.azure.com/.............."
```

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue. The application that sends towards my logic apps sets the following header (Unfortunately, I cannot modify this application)

authorization   Basic Og==

Although I use the HTTP trigger URL that includes the SAS token, I still get back the following

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "DirectApiAuthorizationRequired",
        "message": "The request must be authenticated only by Shared Access scheme."
    }
}
```

There seem to be two ways to drop the header :
* Using APIM (API manager)
* Using Function proxy

https://devkimchi.com/2017/12/07/securing-sas-token-from-azure-logic-apps/
https://www.bruttin.com/2017/07/07/secure-serverless-architecture.html

Choice between both is depending on load & cost [function proxy seems to be the most affordable if it is just for removing headers]

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the full URL generated by your HTTP trigger that URL includes the SAS token for your API as a parameter in the URL it self.

otherwise you can`t send auth headers to your HTTP trigger

Answer (score 0):

when Http triggered logic app exposed via API manager need to remove 'Authorization' header before calling the Back end 
can use API manager policies for this